# Putting an instance of Program in the Main method

Tags: c#

I've got the following in a console application:

```
class Program {


    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Program myProgram = new Program();

        if (myProgram.foo() == true) {
            myProgram.bar();
        }
     }

     public bool foo() {
     //check some stuff 
     }

     public void bar() {
     //do some stuff 
     }

}
```

Is creating an instance of Program in the Program's Main method bad practise and prone to problems?

Comment: Can't you declare the methods `static`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: yes. Just make your two methods `static` and then you won't need to create an instance.

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        if (Program.foo() == true) {
            Program.bar();
        }
     }

    public static bool foo() {
     //check some stuff 
    }

    public static void bar() {
     //do some stuff 
    }
```

Comment: nice ... some folks get very precious about their answers